# Connection through Amman

Tags: visas, transit-visas, jordan, royal-jordanian

I'm a Pakistani national and will be flying from Moscow to Cairo via Amman on Royal Jordanian Airline. My Layover in Amman is around 10 hours, if I wish to not leave the airport do I need to get a visa in advance. I called the embassy in Pakistan and they weren't really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You do not require a transit visa for Jordan.

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 48 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Source: Timatic using [Emirates'](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&DC=EG&DV=Egypt&TC=JO&TV=Jordan&h=3b51ab13fa46c411afa6b6b9b65d117d2e7e5ee8) website